# How to check if a GPS coordinate is in one of 5 polygons?

Tags: android, algorithm, polygon, point, coordinate

I have 5 polygons on my Google Map. Also, I have current coordinates of a user. I tried checking if the user is in one of the polygons by using the "point in polygon?" algorithm and it works every time. But I need to check in which of the five polygons the user is. Do you have any suggestions for this problem?
Thank you!

Edit: This is the function for finding out if the point is in the polygon. I don't want to run it for every of the five polygons, is there any other way to do it?

```
private boolean is_in_polygon(int noOfPointsPolygon, double[] verticesX, double[] verticesY, LatLng location){

    int j;
    boolean c = false;
    int i;
      for (i = 0, j = noOfPointsPolygon-1 ; i < noOfPointsPolygon; j = i++) {
        if ( ((verticesX[i] > location.latitude != (verticesX[j] > location.latitude)) &&
        (location.longitude < (verticesX[j] - verticesX[i]) * (location.latitude - verticesY[i]) / (verticesY[j] - verticesY[i]) + verticesX[i]) ) ) 
            c = !c;
      }
      return c;
```

Comment: Could would provide a code sample of what you have tried?

Comment: `I don't want to run it for every of the five polygons...` Why? Would that lead to a *relevant and measurable* performance problem?

Comment: Well I guess yes, because I plan having more than 100 polygons. I think that then it would be really slow and painful to go through all polygons.

Comment: You could try checking against bounding boxes first.

Comment: Could you tell me why would it be a better solution?